# Upload file to S3's presigned url by using uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile: alway failed

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, nsurlsession

I have below code to upload a file to s3

```
if (_fileSURL) {
                NSDictionary *attrs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:[_fileSURL path] error:nil];
                [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld",[attrs[NSFileSystemSize] longLongValue]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

//                _uploadData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:_fileSURL];
//                [[self.currentSession uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:_uploadData] resume]; //This one works
                [[self.currentSession uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:_fileSURL] resume]; //This one gets 403 error
}
```

If I use `uploadTaskWithRequest:fromData`, it will be successful but the one `fromFile` is alway failed. I would like to use `fromFile` API but it seems to be unusable. Anyone know how to upload file to s3 without loading the whole file into memory, please give advise.
Thanks.

Comment: why are you using `uploadTaskWithRequest:fromData` to upload on `AmazonS3`. As amazon already provides its own iOS sdk, use it. Demo & sdk is available [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios). Latest version & example on their [official website](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transferutility.html)

Comment: I knew the aws2 sdk, but it seems that it is in development. And because I just upload the file to a pre-signed url which is provided by the server, so I think it is quite simple. Anyway I will look at the sdk and see if it help. Thanks

Comment: latest version(2.3.0) of aws is in beta mode only previous versions are stable, use them. Use TransferManager class to upload.